# Circular iteration of std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

In my application I need the ability to traverse a doubly linked list starting from any arbitrary member of the list and continuing past the end(), wrapping around to the begin() and continue until the traversal reaches where it started.

I decided to use `std::list` for the underlying data structure and wrote a `circulate` routine to achieve this. However it's showing certain unexpected behavior when it's wrapping around from end() to begin(). Here's my implementation

```
template <class Container, class BiDirIterator>
void circulate(Container container, BiDirIterator cursor,
  std::function<void(BiDirIterator current)> processor)
{
  BiDirIterator start = cursor;
  do {
    processor(cursor);
    cursor++;
    if (cursor == container.end()) {
      cursor = container.begin(); // [A]
    }
  } while (cursor != start);
}

// ...

typedef int T;
typedef std::list<T> TList;
typedef TList::iterator TIter;

int count = 0;
TList l;
l.push_back(42);
circulate<TList, TIter>(
  l, l.begin(),
  [&](TIter cur) {
    std::cout << *cur << std::endl;
    count++;
  }
);
```

The output is:

```
42
-842150451
```

When I step through the code I see that the line marked [A] is never reached. The cursor is never equal to `container.end()`. Surprisingly, invoking `++` on that cursor, takes it to `container.begin()` in next pass automatically. (I suppose that's specific to this STL implementation).

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are taking `Container` by value.  This causes a copy so the iterators returned by `container.end()` and `container.begin()` are not that same as the iterator passed to the function.  Instead if you pass `Container` by reference then the code works correctly.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d1f983db6ed4a5)